# How do you map a keyboard key in Python 2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I was wondering how do you map a key in python 2.7 to do something, like if you pressed 'a' (without having to hit enter), you would get a print statement.
Thanks a bunch in advance!

Comment: Sounds like you want something for a specific editor/interpreter because I don't think Python itself does this

Comment: I'm not sure there's a good, built-in, portable way to do this, but if you're on Unix, the [curses](https://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html) library gives you the tools to handle this and a bunch of related tasks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use Tkinter or PyQT or some other library that offers event handling. For example:

```
import Tkinter as tk

def key_press(event):
    print event.char
    return event.char
    # Or whatever processing you might want.

tk_app = tk.Tk()
tk_app.bind('<KeyPress>', key_press)
tk_app.mainloop()
```

Comment: So would I replace key_press with the letter key I want to use? Thanks